# C++ application for iPad

Tags: software-recommendation, ipad

I came across an iPad2 application that allows a user to write Python programs on their iPad.

Though this framework was only limited to Python's maths functions I was wondering if there is a similar application that will let you write C++ applications on the iPad2?

Comment: can you link to the app?

Comment: Possble Duplicate: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/9548/is-there-a-c-compiler-for-ipad/

Comment: @Enrico Susatyo: Here's the link to the app http://itunes.apple.com/za/app/python-math/id429450202?mt=8

Comment: @Draco wow that is a serious implementation of python interpreter. I'm not sure how to answer your question now.

Comment: The app doesn't let you write python programs even though it does use the python interpreter and lets you store values and load modules that are built into the app. Embedding a compiler is a whole different ball of wax.

Comment: There are some good links here as well - http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/61285/is-there-any-c-compiler-for-ipad2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you can't compile and run apps from the iPad itself, but there are many text editors in the App Store that support what is called syntax highlighting.  You could then take these files and compile and run them on your Mac or PC.

The reason you won't find apps allowing you to compile code in the App Store is because Apple forbids apps that run external code (code that wasn't bundled with the app).  I'm not quite sure how this Python app got through, but I wouldn't be surprised if it was pulled from the store at some point.

Some text editors that support C++ highlighting are Textastic Code Editor and CodeToGo, but you can find many by searching for "code editor" or "syntax highlighting" (without the quotes) in the App Store.  The interesting thing about CodeToGo is it will let you run your code on a remote server for free if you have an internet connection.  So, if running your code on the iPad is important, CodeToGo might be a good choice for you.

Comment: This question answer are very similar to a question asked earlier this year.

http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/9548/is-there-a-c-compiler-for-ipad/9550#9550