# is there any c++ compiler for ipad2?

Tags: ipad

I am a student in college and just started to learn C++. I have an iPad 2 and no computer (it broke and I will not buy another one). So I want to find an app that seems like codeblock for Windows. The ability to run code and maybe can fix it is a big plus. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Many/most(?) colleges offer computers for students to use.  You could install an SSH or VNC client on your iPad, and connect to a networked computer which has a C++ compiler.

Answer (score 2):

No fully functional IDE exists on iOS to make runnable apps without jailbreaking  but you can sign up for a free Amazon Web service account and get an ssh client and program "on the iPad" assuming you have a network account.

An app like [nimbus](http://nimbustouch.com) or [textastic](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/textastic-code-editor/id383577124?mt=8) would be an ideal companion once you were clear how compiling elsewhere fit your desire to learn.

Xcode is currently only available for Mac OS X to develop programs that run iOS and cocoa touch (not which is very much not C++ - even though Xcode can be used for C++).

Have a look at this question on learning C which will apply almost entirely to C++ on iOS.

[Is there a C compiler for iPad?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/9548/5472)

Answer (score 2):

Is your iPad jailbroken? If yes, download mobile terminal (a commandline) , vim (the text editor) and the gnu c compiler from cydia, and google for a file "iosgcc.zip", download, unzip, and enter the terminal and install the package of g++.
The way to jailbreak depends on the version of your iOS, visit www.jailbreakme.com as a reference.

Answer (score 1):

There is no compiler that runs on the iPad. There are numerous web apps that will accomplish what you're probably looking for.  This of course assumes that you are not hoping to use an iPad as a development environment.

Have a look at:

- [CompileOnline](http://www.compileonline.com/compile_cpp_online.php): Has C++ and many other languages. It's simple with no account necessary.
- [CodePad](http://codepad.org): Very simple. For short snippets only.
- [Compilr](https://compilr.com): Requires registration, but is more like a full-blown Web-ide app with storage available for your code.

Google searches will get you further.  If you are looking for short, snippet based online compiler / interpreters abound.  Compilr works with the iPad and is looks to be sufficient enough to support small projects or college-level coursework.

Answer (score 0):

The development environment for iPad is called XCode and runs on Macs only.

I would suggest you should look into anything that will allow you to enter code,compile it and run it in a browser window instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try CppCode ios app - http://www.cppcode.info. No jailbreak required, no internet required, free(mium)

Answer (score -2):

If it helps, there is [Java for iPad](https://itunes.apple.com/ch/app/java-programming-language/id486207896?mt=8) on App Store but you will have to pay to compile

Comment: Not sure if these apps are all that useful, but for completeness, it should be added that there is also a C++ for iPad app by the same author: https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/c++-programming-language/id461327665?mt=8